# List of everything installed. Not just those with uninstallers

Tags: windows-10, script, windows-registry, path

I've been trying for some time to get a list of everything installed on Window 10. Neither WMIC nor powershell return a complete list.

For example,
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate | Format-Table –AutoSize

Only returns items that have an entry in the uninstall registry.

get-ciminstance win32_product |select-object name,installlocation is the same as the above.

Wmic product get name,installlocation gives me a different list, with some cross overs.

What:
I'm trying to create a text file from a batch script with a list of absolutely everything. I specifically need the name of the program and the install path.

The output file I'm trying to create will contain username, program name, path.

Why:
I have an automation script that is run after a fresh windows install which imports registry keys IF A PROGRAM exists on disk. The programs, and more importantly, games could be on different drives. The users usually have more than one drive for programs and games, and in one case, use 4 different drives.

So if user A has Doom on drive D;, user B: has it on E: and user C has it on F: I want to know where to look for the program/game path for that user

So if the path is found, any registry keys are imported, if there any programdata, local appdata or appdata folders they are copied. This saves hours of reinstalling from scratch and preserves game saves (for those stored locally), and registry settings etc.

Unfortunately, some programs don't store a path, or it's located in the registry keys specifically for that program. I Guess there will be some manual massaging of the output.

This is what I've got by doing dir *. /s/b >folders.txt on each drive then manually editing out all the subfolders of subfolders and copying and pasting the name of the program

```
Far Cry Primal,D:\Program Files (x86)\Far Cry Primal
Star Wars Jedi - Fallen Order,D:\Program Files (x86)\Star Wars Jedi - Fallen Order
The Sims 4 Island Living,D:\Program Files (x86)\The Sims 4 Island Living
Valorant,D:\Program Files (x86)\Valorant
Apex,D:\Program Files (x86)\Origin Games\Apex
Portal 2,D:\Program Files (x86)\Valve\Portal 2
Cities Skylines,I:\Games\Cities Skylines Mass Transit
SWKotor,I:\Program Files\LucasArts\SWKotOR
Command and Conquer Remastered Collection,I:\Program Files (x86)\Command and Conquer Remastered Collection
Mass Effect,I:\Program Files (x86)\Mass Effect
Mass Effect Andromeda,I:\Program Files (x86)\Mass Effect Andromeda
Minecraft,I:\Program Files (x86)\Minecraft
Serious Sam 3 BFE,I:\Program Files (x86)\Serious Sam 3 BFE
Star Wars - Galactic Battlegrounds,I:\Program Files (x86)\Star Wars -     Galactic Battlegrounds
Doom 3 BFG Edition,I:\Program Files (x86)\Bethesda Softworks\Doom 3 BFG Edition
```

Is there any way to do this all from a command line? The creation of this list is to be done by a backup script which saves everything for later restoration once Windows has been reinstalled.

Or perhaps some other way of knowing where to check for and restore stuff to?

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Define "installed". Do you count programs that people have randomly copied to some location as it having been "installed" (I wouldn't) or is there some specific criteria? "Installing" can be seen as a specific situation with consequences such as appearing in the installed software lists you have found. Otherwise without scanning every file in a system and comparing it to a clean system how would you know what was there? Are you only counting `.exe` files or all types of executables?

Comment: Installed through the use of an installer (whether MSI, exe or other). Not portable installations. The presence of a folder, whilst not foolproof, is the best I have to go on. If the folder for a game/program exists I will then import registry and copy files. Applies only to stuff not on the C:\ drive as that is already catered for by the script which installs such programs from scratch. Any settings for those are already backed up before the Windows install is started. Some games are so old they don't write registry, but may have saved games or config files that can be backed up/restored.

Answer (score 0):

Usually programs get installed from MSI, EXE and Chocolatey. There are Powershell CMDLets, which will help you to see them. A one-liner to do this (Show in gridview listing all properties):

```
Get-Package | 
  Where-Object {$_.ProviderName -in @('Programs','msi','chocolatey')} | 
    Select-Object * | 
      Out-GridView -Title "Installed Programs"
```

There are more providers like NuGet, PowershellGet or Microsoft Update (msu).

The most important properties are:

- **Name**: Program name.
- **FastPackageReference**: Uninstall string, or Registry key to reference to the QuietUninstallString.
- **ProviderName**: The Provider Name.
- **SwidTagText**: Useful information in XML format.
- **Version**: Version number
- **Source**: Install location

There are also lot of properties, see in the GridView. You can use `Select-Object` to order, select and filter properties. Here is the example for only six important properties:

```
Get-Package | 
  Where-Object {$_.ProviderName -in @('Programs','msi','chocolatey')} | 
    Select-Object Name,FastPackageRefernce,ProviderName,Version,Source,SwidTagText | 
      Out-GridView -Title "Installed Programs"
```

You can omit `Out-Gridview` if you like.

Comment: Thanks. Sadly the above doesn't capture everything. For example, the first thing I looked for was Doom Eternal. Not listed. It seems to be only programs installed on C:\, which is the only drive I'm not interested in. I want to search all drives, and the number of drives, and the letters might be unknown. Perhaps I worded the original question poorly. I'll rewrite it

Answer (score 0):

For decades, I have been installing all programs on a second hard drive. Over time, I have found that most programs run without problem even after a new installation if I simply launch the appropriate *.exe file of the respective program from that program's installation folder.

As for the settings, you could try to simply copy the entire user folder of the old installation back to the user folder of the new installation using a live CD. After this, also most of the program settings from the previous installation should be present again.

Also, there is an installation tracker called [Martau Total Uninstall](https://www.martau.com), which I have also been using for decades.

Total Uninstall can read out all files and registry entries of an installed program even after having installed and used the program, and export them as a ZIP archive. This archive can then be [restored on a new Windows installation](https://www.martau.com/document/transfer-programs-to-new-pc.php), or even on another PC, in such a way that the program and all its settings work again.